# Lucene.NET: Recommended way to index and search for DateTime and TimeSpan fields

Tags: c#, datetime, lucene.net, timespan

Seemingly basic task: index a `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` fields and do range and exact searches over them later on.

The Internets are all over the place: tutorials referencing outdated versions of Lucene.NET; manuals recommending storing dates and times as ints, as longs, as strings; documents that advise using `NumericRangeQueries`; blog posts that recommend `TermRangeQueries`; GitHub comments that say that numeric is the way to go, and oh my.

For the love of all that is memory managed and garbage collected, let's compile a ultra-comprehensive and super-up-to-date reference for those poor souls who embark on a full-text-search journey:

1. What `Analyzer` should be and should *not* be used when indexing dates and times
2. How should dates and times be stored in a `Document` and what `Field` types should be used
3. How to do *range queries* for *dates* (`DateTime` values) and *times* (`TimeSpan` values)

   - ...using standard `QueryParser`
   - ...when manually constructing `Query` objects
   - ...when writing your own `QueryParser`
4. How to do *exact matches* for *dates* (`DateTime` values) and *times* (`TimeSpan` values)

   - ...using standard `QueryParser`
   - ...when manually constructing `Query` objects
   - ...when writing your own `QueryParser`

Answer (score 1):

Not really the forum for this sort of discussion (SO is for Q&A). I'd happily collaborate on a wiki... But some comments to get you going.

The reason there aren't any definitive articles is because the answer is "it depends". As usual with query stores, the answers will be different depending on how you want to query it.

One thing is sure... **always** convert to UTC

I usually favor using numeric fields. Convert dates into semantic numbers. So 10 Aug 2016 = 20160810. Datetimes just extend to add HH, MM and SS. Some utility functions make this simple enough.

I had a system where the "precision" of each field could be defined.

This makes it human read/write-able and enables ranges. Though it does mean that non range queries are not pretty.

The same scheme can be used with string fields with UN_TOKENIZED or the Keyword analyzer. In this case you could write a TokenFilter/Analyzer to parse the entered date and convert to the standard format above or the standard ISO format which is also sortable (so that ranges work).

Some of these choices will depend on how the searching side will work...

If it needs to parse a query as a string then the Lucene QueryParser is a little limiting. I had my own parser (based on Irony.net).

If it's behind an API this separate arguments for from/to then that part can be constructed manually and combined with a parsed part using BooleanQuery or Filter (Filter is good if the same dates/ranges are going to be reused).

So, there you have it... a non-answer answer. There is no "one size fits all". Think of it a little like designing a DataWarehouse. The design somewhat depends on the queries/reports you want to create